# Get Filename From PHAsset swift 5 IOS13

Tags: swift5, phasset

**My Question is how we get file Name From PHAsset Which Are Picked By gallery**

```
var allSmallPic: [PHAsset] = []

PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: allSmallPic[indexPath.row], targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil) { (image, info) in
        
        
        
        cell.ImageVieww.image = image
        cell.Labell.text = "\(String(describing: info!))"
        print(info!)

                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you Know PHAsset is representation of an image, video, or Live Photo in the Photos library.**

So I want to show the file names into my tableViewCell Like this
[image]

when no results found i'm start read documentations and i found PHAssetResource and they help me to Get image name

```
let resource1 = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for:self.allSmallPic[indexPath.row])
    print("Get resources\(resource1)")
    cell.Labell.text = resource1[0].originalFilename
```

The **allSmallPic** is global array which store PHAsset

Answer (score 0):

```
    let resource1 = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for:self.allSmallPic[indexPath.row])
    print("Get resources\(resource1)")
    cell.Labell.text = resource1[0].originalFilename
```